# Visual Studio 2015 CE vs. XCode 6.4 - Different Compile-time errors

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2015

I usually use both above mentioned IDEs but I have noticed that this little code (below) in VS 2015 CE compiles and works, while in XCode it returns me an error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)
{
    int count_s = 0;

    while (s[count_s] != 0)
    {
        int count_x = 0;
        while (x[count_x] != 0)
        {
            if (s[count_s] == x[count_x])
            {
                cout << "Found match " << x[count_x] << " at X[" << count_x
                << "] with " << s[count_s] << " at S[" << count_s
                << "]" << endl;
                return 0;
                break;
            }
            ++count_x;
        }
        ++count_s;
    }

    cout << "Match " << *x << " not found" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char* p = new char[6]{ "Zorro" };
    char* p1 = new char[4]{ "Zio" };
    findx(p, p1);
    delete[] p;
    delete[] p1;
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I got in XCode are:

```
char* p = new char[6]{ "Zorro" }; // Initializer-string for char array is too long
char* p1 = new char[4]{ "Zio" }; // Initializer-string for char array is too long
```

Thank you!

P.S. What do you feel to advice? I prefer XCode but I am not an experienced programmer so I trust you!

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Both [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63582d681bc73fdb) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b81cb6c1b2126956) give an error

Comment: Following up on @NathanOliver's comment, your IDEs merely inform you of the errors reported by your compilers. Proper scoping of your problem is important towards understanding the issues.

Comment: What version of 2015 are you using?  I have 2015 RC V 14.0.22823.1 and I get `Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Version *14.0.23107.0 D14REL* does not issue an error. This is the RTM version of *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015*.

Comment: @NathanOliver I got VS 2015 v. 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, not the RC! I guess this is the final one. I have attached an image of my success compiling and running!

Comment: I would say it is a bug in your version then.

Comment: What should the correct form be then?

Comment: Or maybe g++ and clang have a bug. This seems to be a case of [aggregate initialization: Character arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Character_arrays) (see [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)).

Comment: I have had an exhaustive answer in this thread regarding this error, for who wants to know more about:  http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/171508/